# Check if file starts with values from list and if not kill it

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop, delete-file

I am trying to delete files based on the file name's starting characters.

I have an Excel file with numbers in column A. These numbers are either 4, 5 or 6 digits.

I have a file folder with files which may not start with these digits from a range from Excel file.
These files in folders are of different types.

The naming convention:
4563_listofitems.pdf,65475_skusdec.doc etc.

My goal is to loop through files and check if the starting characters of the file are included in the A range of the Excel sheet.
If so (there may be up to six files starting with such number) create a folder named with the found starting characters and move the files into the folder.
Else delete (kill) that file.

How do I check the files names against the list?

My code for looping

```vb
Sub loopf

Dim filen as variant
Filen =dir("c:\test\")

While filen <>""
    If instr(1,filen,10000)=1 then
        'Here I want check against the values from range but unsure how ,should I somehow loop through the range ?
        Filen=dir
    End if
Wend

End sub
```

Comment: Dir function doesn't return the list https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008898);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a value is contained within a known list, I like using the [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) Object. It has the function `Exists` which checks if a value is listed within the Dictionary.

So before you loop through the files, you just need to add every one of your accepted numbers into the dictionary. Then while looping though the files check if `Dictionary.Exists(Value)`. If it exists, then the value is good, if not then `Kill`.

Here's how I would set that up:

```vb
Sub loopf()
    Dim AcceptedPrefixes As Object
    Set AcceptedPrefixes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim PrefixRange As Range
    Set PrefixRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In PrefixRange.Cells
        If Cell <> "" And Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(Cell.Value) Then
            AcceptedPrefixes.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 0
        End If
    Next

    Dim Directory As String
    Directory = "c:\test\"

    Dim filen As Variant
    filen = Dir(Directory)
    While filen <> ""
        Dim FilePrefix As String
        FilePrefix = Split(filen, "_")(0)
        
        If Not AcceptedPrefixes.exists(FilePrefix) Then
            Kill Directory & filen
        End If
        
        filen = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution killed all files. Not sure how to check if prefixes were added to dictionary?

Comment: Add `AcceptedPrefixes.Keys` to the watch list. That will show the list of prefixes that have been added to the dictionary. The function `Exists` is extremely literal, it must match case, and have the same leading & trailing spaces (if any).

Comment: I used `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A5")` as a placeholder in my example code. When using this code in your project, be sure to edit that line to point at your actual list of prefixes.

Comment: Oh yeah I amended the code ofc interms of range and directory link, after adding watch just now it is filled correctly with variables. One thing I do not understand it is filled with one less variable idk why. Let's say if the list got 10 variables the watch shows 9.there r no duplicates I checked.still it seems everything works correctly untill "ifnotacceptedprefixes.exist never matches there

Comment: Ok,ichecked if it works if I add a specific word in an excel range and at the beggining of one of the files and it did work.must be the name of the files or maybe (format of values 8n range maybe)

Comment: It sounds like there might be problems elsewhere in the project. If you're still having trouble, post a new question with the details of this new issue.

Comment: Discovered it works perfectly if I change the values to text in range so when added to dictionary they are stored in " ". Still it is a pain to change all of them

Comment: Oh got it,if it is stored as double it doesn't work dictionary wise,if as string all OK.

Comment: @Gokuba To handle this issue, you can add a string conversion when adding values to the dictionary, like `AcceptedPrefixes.Add CStr(Cell.Value), 0`. I will add that to my answer as well, for visibility.

Comment: Yes I figured that one, I was sure that I mentioned it in previous comment. Still problem solved.Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Files()
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\test") 
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'do somthing
Next oFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok,but how do I loop based on the values?

Comment: oFile is the object if you'd like to check the name use oFile.Name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/files-property